# How to change Notepad++ background color for changed text lines?

Tags: notepad++

There's a bright pink (#ffc286) background color for updated (not saved) text lines, and bright green color (#b5ffb5) for changed and saved text lines. This background is the same for any color style.

I couldn't find it in Style Configurator (I thought it might be Incremental highlight, but it's not), and it's not in global settings,

I've looked for this value in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` and `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`, but it's not there.

Anyone knows where to change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Go to plugins>Location Navigate>Show List and option>Clear all.

Comment: This was enough of an annoyance to make me uninstall this plugin. Thank you!

Comment: @Brady: Plugins > Location Navigate > Uncheck "Mark Changed Line", thus no need for uninstalling one of the best N++ plug-ins.

Answer (score 4):

There are two fields 'Mark Color' and 'Save Color' near 'Clear All' button at the botom of the 'Location History' pane. You can click on this field and select any color that you want to use here.