# How to change Notepad++ ugly background color on new unsaved windows

Tags: themes, notepad++, background-color

Notepad++ has a uniquely useful feature -- you can open a new tab and paste some text in and it will remember that text forever without saving it to any formal location. I have used it this way for a long time as I do a lot of experimental stuff when working with Hyperledger blockchain code and data.

I also like the style configurator, and particularly the solarized-light theme, which is easy on the eyes.

BUT ... when I create my unsaved tabs (new39, new40, etc...) they get an obnoxious background color that is unpleasant to look at and partially obscures text based on the lighter foreground font I am using. I've been searching for a solution off and on for days, and it is driving me nuts.

So does anyone know how to make it stop treating unsaved data so poorly? It is the one feature that makes me want to just use vscode for everything, despite its lack of the ability to act as a persistent cache for random unsaved data.

** EDIT (March 2019): The first comment on this question helped a bit IIRC but fresh installs seem to behave much better, which makes me think that I had managed over time to confuse the app. But in my opinion the choice now is to simply use VSCode, which has similar properties to NP++ but with a much richer and actively maintained plugin / extension system. So as much as I like NP++, it has aged itself out of my current tool set.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845235/how-to-change-notepad-background-color-for-changed-text-lines/17625876#17625876 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... my definitive solution since about mid-2018 is to switch to vscode. The reality a few years after my initial complaint:

- vscode implements the feature I was using (persistent unsaved tabs) and runs on all OSs that matter
- notepad++ eventually started working again when I reinstalled it, which tells me that its state is corruptible as I experienced
- vscode has so many extensions and plugins that it is superior in pretty much every way to notepad++ (Note: my opinion and YMMV), although I do have fond memories of that app

I won't go back and I consider this issue closed.

Answer (score 2):

The color of your new window is dependant on the theme you have loaded. You can change these theme colors by going settings->style configurator. My best guess is that the specific attribute is going to be in the Global Styles dialog. It should be easy enough to cycle through those options until the color comes up.

Best of luck.

Comment: My second one-line paragraph makes it clear that I am familiar with the styles. The issue is that a newly created and not saved window substitues an obnoxious background color that is not part of the theme as far as I can tell. Try pasting in some text. The background color there does not appear in any of the global styles.

Comment: From my understanding all colors are drawn from the theme. It must be one of the settings. Are you using one of the default themes? If so which one?

Comment: It affects them all unfortunately. I've tries the default (which works best, since text is black even in this nasty mode), solarized-light, which is easy on the eyes but is unreadable when the nasty background color hits on paste, and several others. I've looked extensively and cannot find this color in any of the themes I am using. I also cannot find any plugins that look like the culprit. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

On the version 8, during the installation process, there's options: check the "theme", you can check all themes. and thereafter, go to "prefereence", find the "Dark Mode", check "enable". That's it, all clear and beautiful.

Comment: I appreciate your keeping this thread up to date. I still use vscode over NP++, and vscode has climbed from way back in the pack to be number one these days, so it is better than ever now. Still, for a small and fairly light editor, NP++ is a nice option to have.